# Crystal Report for visual studio crashes on 'Report Preview'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

this is new for me, i have a new machine(x64) with win8 and everytime i try to see the 'Report Preview' i get this error on my event log:

```
Naam van toepassing met fout: devenv.exe, versie: 10.0.40219.1, tijdstempel: 0x4d5f2a73
Naam van module met fout: craxddrt.dll, versie: 13.0.0.99, tijdstempel: 0x4cc41346
Uitzonderingscode: 0xc000041d
Foutmarge: 0x001642bc
Id van proces met fout: 0x1234
Starttijd van toepassing met fout: 0x01ced3d13b896e1a
Pad naar toepassing met fout: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Pad naar module met fout: C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\craxddrt.dll
Rapport-id: 9bcabf7a-3fc4-11e3-be77-54bef702c245
Volledige pakketnaam met fout: 
Relatieve toepassings-id van pakket met fout:
```

My old machine had win7(x64).

I have also a printscreen of the error on this link(this happens with empty reports aswell as reports with data):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm85x.jpg

Regards,
Rui Nunes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not fluent in Dutch, but it seems that you are missing some files. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe and C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\craxddrt.dll are your clues here. Please read [this](http://scn.sap.com/message/10000424) post on CR and 64 bit systems.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the link you provided me, it looks like the CR does not support 64bit. I will try to install the 32bit for vs2010 and see if that helps, about the error, im not missing any files, the message tells me where the crash is happening in this case on devenv.exe(vs2010) and craxddrt.dll(this is where the crash happens)

Once again thanks for the link

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I'm German but never learned any Dutch, so I had to guess a little. Hope you get it resolved, I found the post to be pretty informative.

Comment: Hey Chris, its fine ;). I have download a new version of cr for 32bit from their website and it looks like it worked, i had to unninstall all the 64bit version of CR and then restart the pc.. That post was really informative. Thanks once again.